# Unable to retrieve jobs through Rundeck API using Python

Tags: python, rundeck

I'm exploring the rundeck api to return a list of jobs. I manually creatd two jobs through the UI. However, I ended up getting 0 jobs through that api. I'm having hard time to figure out what's going on in the process.

Below is my code example:

```
import urllib2
import logging
import ssl
RUNDECK_TOKEN = 'My_API_Token'

class Rundeck():
    def get_full_url(self):
        return 'https://rdurl:8443/rundeckpro/api/14/project/Sandbox/jobs?authtoken=' + RUNDECK_TOKEN


    def make_api_call(self):
        context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPSHandler(context=context))
        request = urllib2.Request(self.get_full_url())
        try:
            return opener.open(request, timeout=30)
        except urllib2.HTTPError as err:
            if err.code == 409:
                return 'Running'
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error('Exception : %s', e)
            return False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = Rundeck()
    print jobs.get_full_url()
    print jobs.make_api_call().read()
```

The output is:

```
<jobs count='0' />
```

Thanks for the helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your script works perfect fine for me.

Check your Rundeck ACL, your api key owner may not have read access to the jobs you created.

Test output:

```
tmp $ python test.py 
http://localhost:4440/api/14/project/TestProject/jobs?authtoken=OyFXX1q4UzhTUe7deOUIPJKkrUnEwZlo
<jobs count='3'>
  <job id='63385df9-8898-48e9-ae8a-047b548915cd' href='http://localhost:4440/api/18/job/63385df9-8898-48e9-ae8a-047b548915cd' permalink='http://localhost:4440/project/TestProject/job/show/63385df9-8898-48e9-ae8a-047b548915cd'>
    <name>TEST</name>
    <group />
    <project>TestProject</project>
    <description></description>
  </job>
  <job id='02a41aaa-eb50-4831-8762-80b798468cbe' href='http://localhost:4440/api/18/job/02a41aaa-eb50-4831-8762-80b798468cbe' permalink='http://localhost:4440/project/TestProject/job/show/02a41aaa-eb50-4831-8762-80b798468cbe'>
    <name>TestJob</name>
    <group />
    <project>TestProject</project>
    <description>TestJob Description</description>
  </job>
  <job id='9b2ac9e9-0350-4494-a463-b43ba1e458ab' href='http://localhost:4440/api/18/job/9b2ac9e9-0350-4494-a463-b43ba1e458ab' permalink='http://localhost:4440/project/TestProject/job/show/9b2ac9e9-0350-4494-a463-b43ba1e458ab'>
    <name>TestJob2</name>
    <group />
    <project>TestProject</project>
    <description></description>
  </job>
</jobs>
```

Comment: The user has all the access in the ACL. I also find out a problem is that I will be able to use https://rdurl:8443/rundeckpro/api/14/project/Sandbox/jobs?authtoken=My_TOKEN in my browser and see all the jobs after I login..